# What does "contingent upon proof of employment eligibility" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

An offer letter I received mentions my position as

> You will hold the position of Software Architect (contingent upon
>   proof of employment eligibility).

What does it mean?

> contingent upon proof of employment eligibility

**Possible upon proof of employment eligibility?**

Comment: You can't just stop at definition 1..... Definition 4 at [m-w.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contingent): dependent on or conditioned by something else <payment is contingent on fulfillment of certain conditions>

Comment: So you can't get the job unless you have proof that you are eligible to be employed by them.

Comment: @Hellion Oh ok. So it means they need my "proof of eligibility" and maybe they will issue another offer letter after that.

Comment: @PrayagUpd It doesn't imply that they will issue another offer letter.  It implies that this one will be in force assuming your proof of eligibility is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Contingent* comes to us from the Latin *con* (with) + *tangere* (to touch), and in this usage, instead of "touches with" we would say "hinges upon."  In other words, "depends upon."  So the company will hire you as a Software Architect, but keeping that position depends on your ability to show that you're eligible for employment.  For instance, you might have to show that you have the required credentials or the proper visa.

Comment: Great answer, so I assume its just proof of eligibility not "ability". Not afraid of ability though :) I was wondering what does it mean

Comment: @PrayagUpd Thank you.  Not ability.  Human resources will demand proof of eligibility long before anyone figures out whether you have the ability to design software.

Comment: Got it, thank you for helping me with my first job in US :)